# Single Collection Inheritance or multiple collections?

Tags: mongodb

Assuming I have data of high school students across the country. Each high school data are not related each other and also never needed to be related to each other (compartmentalized). Which one is recommended if I use mongoDB:

1) Create single collection inheritance with the following attributes:

`high_school_id, student_id, name, address`

2) Create multiple collections (possibly thousands) with the following attributes:

`student_id, name, address`

The name of collection will follow `school_data_<X>` format, where `X` is the `high_school_id`. So, to query, my program can dynamically construct the collection name.

I came from MySQL, PostgreSQL background where having thousands tables are not common (So, option (1) is far more makes sense). How is it in MongoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use the first option, because MongoDB has a limit on the number of collections. More about this read [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#namespaces).

You may want to consider a third option: create a collection with the students, where each student's record will include a high school data. There is nothing wrong in the duplication of data, you should not thinking about this in MongoDB, but you should thinking about more convenient way working with data.